# Performance impact of .End(xlDown) vs. .End(xlUp)

Tags: vba, excel

Assume you have between 25,000 and and 50,000 rows of data in columns 1 to 5,000, every column may have a different number of rows. All data is continuous i.e. there are no empty rows in a column and no empty columns.

Take the following code into consideration

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

With Ws1
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i,1).Value = "Column: " & i & "has " & LastRow & "rows."
    Next i
End With
```

In this code I've found the number of the last column and row by using the `.End(xlToLeft)` and `.End(xlUp)` which looks from the end of the sheet back to where the data is.

My question is, do you incur a performance penalty for looking back from the end and by extension, if your data is continuous it would be better to use `.End(xlToRight)` and `.End(xlDown)` or is this difference negligible?

Comment: [time your macro](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to follow the excellent suggestion of @Davesexcel an do some time experiments:

```
Sub time_test(m As Long, n As Long, k As Long)
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, sum As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim start As Double, elapsed As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastrow = Range("A:A").Rows.Count
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, m)).ClearContents
    For i = 1 To m
        r = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(n, k)
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.ClearContents
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(r, i)).Value = 1
    Next i
    Debug.Print m & " columns initialized with " & n & " to " & k & " rows of data in each"
    Debug.Print "testing xlDown..."

    start = Timer
    For i = 1 To m
        sum = sum + Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Value
    Next i
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print sum & " columns processed in " & elapsed & " seconds"

    sum = 0

    Debug.Print "testing xlUp..."
    start = Timer
    For i = 1 To m
        sum = sum + Cells(lastrow, i).End(xlUp).Value
    Next i
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print sum & " columns processed in " & elapsed & " seconds"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Used like this:

```
Sub test()
    time_test 1000, 5000, 10000
End Sub
```

This produces the output:

```
1000 columns initialized with 5000 to 10000 rows of data in each
testing xlDown...
1000 columns processed in 0.1796875 seconds
testing xlUp...
1000 columns processed in 0.0625 seconds
```

which suggests that using `xlUp` is better.

On the other hand, if I run `time_test 5000, 500, 1000`

I get the output:

```
5000 columns initialized with 500 to 1000 rows of data in each
testing xlDown...
5000 columns processed in 0.08984375 seconds
testing xlUp...
5000 columns processed in 0.84375 seconds
```

in which the apparent advantage is flipped. I've experimented with a number of different choices for the parameters and am unable to get a clear signal.

If I try to run `time_test 5000, 25000, 50000` (which is what you asked about)  Excel crashes with an error message about Excel lacking resources to finish the task -- before it even reaches the timing stage.

To sum up -- any difference appears to be minor and might depend on the actual number of columns and rows used. If you are in a situation where it might make a difference then you are probably running against Excel memory limits in which case the difference between `xlDown` and `xlUp` is probably the least of your worries.